# How to query recurrence rules in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, calendar, icalendar, recurrence

I have a recurrence table that stores the iCalendar RFC 5545 Recurrence Rule string. Ex:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=2
```

Does anyone know of any postgres functions similar to do the following?

```
get_events_between(date,date)
```

Where It would just query the recurrence table and parse the rrule string.

Comment: Hello @terezzy, do you have some news about this?

Answer (score 9):

In PostgreSQL, as of version 14, there is no built-in support for RFC-5545 Recurrence Rule format.

But there are some custom extensions out there.

1. [pg_rrule](https://github.com/petropavel13/pg_rrule). When you install it, you should be able to query Ical schedules this way:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM unnest(
    get_occurrences(
        'FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=2'::rrule,
        now(),
        now() + '6 months'::interval
    )
);
```

2. [postgres-rrule](https://github.com/volkanunsal/postgres-rrule)
3. You can get a Python RRULE parser (like [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/)) and embed it postgres using [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html).

Comment: This one looks like it has a lot more functionality (rrule sets, which allow EXRULE as well): https://github.com/volkanunsal/postgres-rrule